# Why are svg rendered tilted (Processing)?

Tags: java, svg, image-processing, processing, rendering

My aim is to remake the classic Freecell card game for Windows Xp on Windows 10 with Processing 3.
To do so I downloaded from [here](https://totalnonsense.com/download/download-vector-playing-cards/) a set of svg files that most resembled the old cards' look.
In my code I have a class called `Deck` that contains an `ArrayList` of cards and, when constructed, it initializes the cards giving them the path for the svg file they need and after also x and y coordinates.

```
class Deck
{
  String[] seeds = {"HEART", "DIAMOND", "CLUB", "SPADE"};
  String[] values = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"};
  ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
  
  Deck()
  {
    //Create the cards and store them into the array.
    for(int seed = 0; seed < seeds.length; seed++)
    {
      for(int value = 0; value < values.length; value++)
      {
        String cardName = seeds[seed] + "-" + values[value] + ".svg";
        cards.add(new Card(cardName));
      }
    }

    //Shuffle the deck.
    //this.shuffle();

    //Give the cards x and y coordinates.
    for(int c = 0; c < cards.size(); c++)
    {
      int x = cardSpace + (cardWidth+cardSpace)*(c%8);
      int y = 32 + cardHeight + edge*2 + cardSpace + 25*(c/8);
      cards.get(c).setxy(x, y);
    }
  }
  
  void shuffle()
  {
    for(int c = cards.size()-1; c > 0; c--)
    {
      int k = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (c + 1));
      Card card = cards.get(c);
      cards.set(c, cards.get(k));
      cards.set(k, card);
    }
  }
  
  void render()
  {
    for(Card card : cards)
    {
      card.render();
    }
  }
}
```

Card class:

```
class Card
{
  PShape svg;
  int x;
  int y;
  
  Card(String svgName)
  {
    this.svg = loadShape(svgName);
  }
  
  void setxy(int x, int y)
  {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  
  boolean isMouseOver()
  {
    return mouseX > x && mouseX < (x+cardWidth) && mouseY > y && mouseY < (y+cardHeight);
  }
  
  void render()
  {
    shape(svg, x, y, cardWidth, cardHeight);
  }
}
```

The `render()` method of the class `Deck` is called once every `draw()` loop, with `frameRate` set to 10.
Anyway, the code works fine, the only problem is in how two svg are rendered, as you can see here:
[image: Application screenshot]
For some reasons, only the *5 of spade* and the inner drawing of the *jack of heart* are completely tilted.
However when opened with Inkscape or any browser they look correctly orientated, thus my confusion.
I tried to use the original versions of those two svg, yet they are still rendered tilted. I tried to compare the xml of those two svg, but I couldn't understand what could be causing the problem.
It may also be processing, but then I would have no idea why or how to fix it.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Adding main sketch file as requested in the comments.
However note that it's stripped off of the upper gray bar and the rectangles.

```
//Global objects.
Deck deck;
//Global objects.

//Global variables.
int edge = 2;
int cardSpace = 15;
int cardWidth = 100;
int cardHeight = 140;
//Global variables.

void settings()
{
  int w = cardWidth*8 + cardSpace*9;
  int h = cardHeight*5 + 32;
  size(w, h);
}

void setup()
{
  frameRate(30);
  
  deck = new Deck();  //Initialized here because of loadImage().
}

void draw()
{
  background(60, 145, 50);
  deck.render();
}
```

Comment: I'm stumped. I downloaded the image files and they seem okay. Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: @KevinWorkman well, this is literally all I did ahah
I downloaded the images and checked them and both in svg editors and browsers they look fine. However when loaded in Processing they look like that.
I could post the `draw()` function, but all that's inside is drawing a bunch of rectangles (the ones you see at the top) and then `deck.render()` is called.

Comment: Without being able to run the code it's going to be pretty hard to debug this any further, so I suggest posting a [mcve]. Note that this should **not** be your full program. Try starting over from scratch and drawing **just** the problematic cards.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I edited the question. Is it better now? Anyway drawing only the problematic cards leads to the same issue, if ones wants to see just the problematic cards it's sufficient to comment out the first for loop in `Deck()` that loads all the cards and add two lines of code to load only the problematic cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it, and this seems to fix it.

In SPADE-5.svg, on line 84/85, remove

```
transform="rotate(180,1744.645,-315.5025)"
```

HEART-11-JACK.svg, on line 123/124, remove

```
transform="rotate(0.33810995,363.27095,269.89449)"
```

(make sure not to delete the `>`)